# How to read a BMP file into a grid of pixels in C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, fread

I'm trying to read in a given BMP file and store it in an image.  I'm confused about the syntax since I'm struggling to understand the .h files given to me.  Here's how I'm going about reading in the image:

```
BMPImage * readImage(FILE * fp) {

// FILL IN

BMPHeader * hp = malloc(sizeof(BMPHeader);

Pixel * p = malloc(sizeof(Pixel));
p -> pixels = malloc(p -> height_px * sizeof(Pixel *));
for(int i = 0; i < p -> height_px; i++){
  p -> pixels[i] = malloc(p -> width_px * sizeof(Pixel));
}

for (i = 0; i < p -> height_px; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < p -> width_px; j++){
    Pixel px = fread(hp, sizeof(Pixel), 1, fp);
    p -> pixels[i][j] = px;
  }
}
return p;
```

}

Here's the .h file:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) BMPHeader  {             // Total: 54 bytes
  uint16_t  type;             // Magic identifier: 0x4d42
  uint32_t  size;             // File size in bytes
  uint16_t  reserved1;        // Not used
  uint16_t  reserved2;        // Not used
  uint32_t  offset;           // Offset to image data in bytes from beginning of file (54 bytes)
  uint32_t  dib_header_size;  // DIB Header size in bytes (40 bytes)
  int32_t   width_px;         // Width of the image
  int32_t   height_px;        // Height of image
  uint16_t  num_planes;       // Number of color planes
  uint16_t  bits_per_pixel;   // Bits per pixel
  uint32_t  compression;      // Compression type
  uint32_t  image_size_bytes; // Image size in bytes
  int32_t   x_resolution_ppm; // Pixels per meter
  int32_t   y_resolution_ppm; // Pixels per meter
  uint32_t  num_colors;       // Number of colors  
  uint32_t  important_colors; // Important colors 
} BMPHeader;

typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) Pixel {
    uint8_t blue;
    uint8_t green;
    uint8_t red;
    uint8_t alpha;
} Pixel;

typedef struct BMPImage {
    BMPHeader header;
    int norm_height; //normalized height
    Pixel * * pixels;
} BMPImage;
```

How should I correct my reading method?

Comment: There is no 2D array in your code! A pointer is not an array. `Pixel **` is a pointer to pointer, not an array of arrays! And C does not support _methods_.

Comment: Isn't that what I'm creating with my mallocs?  I'm essentially creating the memory for 2D array of pixels.

Comment: It is not a good idea to malloc() inside a function since it can have memory garbage collection problem if your allocating too much memory.  Its better to allocate memory from main() and send in a pointer to struct.  At the end of main, you can free up the memory.  This doesn't really matter if your memory allocation size is small, but if it gets big, it matters.

Comment: @Hitmarcurse What Olaf is going on about is that ["arrays" in C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm) have a particular meaning distinct from a list of pointers. "Methods" are functions called on objects, but C doesn't have objects, so they're just functions. None of this is really helpful to you. :) Could you correct your code so it compiles? It's using `Pixel` wrong, there's no `Pixel.pixel`. I suspect it should be a `BMPImage`.

Comment: @Schwern Well, technically, C does have "object"s, but not in the OOP sense. `struct`s are objects, for example. They don't have methods, though; you're correct about that.

Comment: @Schwern: Well, OP at least should consider removing the name 2D array from the question and not even think about a `**` as one. Would be a good start.

Comment: @Nguaial Allocating inside the function is preferred, the same memory will be allocated either way, it's one less thing the user can screw up, and it avoids revealing details of the struct. There should be a `BMPImage_destroy` method to handle freeing. You can compromise and split it into a function to read the header into an already allocated BMPHeader, a function to read the image into an already allocated BMPImage + Pixel array, and a function that does it all for you, including allocation, using the other two functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given how you're struggling with structs, lists, and basic I/O, reading in a [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) is probably over your head right now. I'd suggest trying to populate a simpler struct. If this is for a production code, please use an existing library.

I'm going to do some basic fixups so your code at least compiles, hopefully you can take it from there.

```
BMPImage *readImage(FILE * fp) {
    // Allocate space for the image.
    // This also covers BMPHeader, since it's not a pointer.
    BMPImage *bmp = malloc(sizeof(BMPImage));
    BMPHeader *bmph = &(bmp->header);
```

The basic unit is the `BMPImage` struct. That contains the BMPHeader as well as a pointer to list of Pixels. The `BMPHeader` is not a pointer, the actual memory is contained in the BMPImage struct, so `malloc(sizeof(BMPImage))` also allocates memory for the `BMPHeader`. I've taken a pointer to the `BMPHeader` to make it easier to work with, otherwise the code is sprinkled with `bmp.header->height_x`.

I'll leave populating the BMPHeader to you. Once you've done that...

```
// Allocate space for the pixels.
bmp->pixels = malloc( bmph->height_px * sizeof(Pixel *) );
for(int i = 0; i < bmph->height_px; i++){
    bmp->pixels[i] = malloc(bmph->width_px * sizeof(Pixel));
}
```

I *think* you've basically got the memory allocation right. Your problem was trying to use the `Pixel` struct when you should have been using `BMPImage`. While the height and width comes from the `BMPHeader`.

That isn't really how you should be reading in a BMP since [the size of the pixels are variable according to the `bits_per_pixel` header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_format). Your structs only support the 8bpp format. It also might be compressed. I'm going to assume this is an exercise and not production code, so I'll avoid going further into the details of BMP.

```
// Read in each pixel
for (int i = 0; i < bmph->height_px; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < bmph->width_px; j++){
        Pixel px;

        if( fread(&px, sizeof(Pixel), 1, fp) < 1 ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error while reading bmp: %s", strerror(errno));
            return NULL;
        }

        bmp->pixels[i][j] = px;
    }
}
```

Again, you had the `BMPImage` and `BMPHeader` mixed up with `Pixel`. Furthermore, `fopen` does not return the structure to be read. Instead, you're responsible for allocating the necessary memory (a theme in C). `fopen` returns the number of items read. It's *very* important to do error checking on all file operations, else you'll be left with difficult to understand garbage.

I suspect you can do this much simpler by reading in all the pixels in one big chunk, but I don't know the details of the BMP format.

This is by no means 100% correct, I'm not even sure it's 80% correct, but it'll at least clean up the worst of the confusion.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This explains a lot and is very helpful.  I've made the fixes and a couple of my own mistakes and it compiles now.

Comment: There is no need to allocate memory for px.  All you need is to do is to declare Pixel px;  fread( &px, sizeof(px), 1, fp ); bmp->pixels[i][j] = px;  By doing this you don't need a line for malloc() and free() and don't worry about about unnecessary memory management.

Comment: @Schwern  -  What is this line supposed to do?          bmp->pixels[i][j] = *px;  This line is assigning struct data.  That's all.  Do you agree?

Comment: @Nguaial Oh, right, it's a copy! Sorry, I keep thinking this is an array of Pixel pointers. You're totally right.

Comment: @Schwern - yup!!!  I get this confused all the time myself.  Thanks for putting me in focused mode.  Cheers!!!

Answer (score -1):

Here is untested code.

```
 void readImage(FILE * fp, BMPImage *bpp) {
    Pixel pixel;

    for (i = 0; i < p -> height_px; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < p -> width_px; j++){
           fread(&pixel, sizeof(Pixel), 1, fp);
           bpp->pixels[i][j] = pixel;
       }
   }

  int
  main()
  {
     BMPHeader *hp = malloc(sizeof(* hp));
     FILE *fp;
     int i;

     ... read header info and stored into hp->header
     ... open fp file

     hp->pixels = malloc(bpp->header.width_px * sizeof(Pixel *));

     for( i=0; i<hp->header.width_px; i++ )
        hp->pixels[i] = malloc(bpp->header.height_px * sizeof(Pixel));

     //Send in pointers.
     readImage(fp, hp);

     ... need to free up memory.
```

}

.
First, need to follow composite data structure.

Second, need to free up memory since it looks like it will need a lot of memory.
It is a good practice to allocate/free up memory in one area.

Comment: This wasn't supposed to be a complete code.  Sorry about the confusion.  About pixel assignment to bpp->pixels[i][j] = pixel, that is assigning pixel structure data to pixels[i][j].  So there is no need to allocate pixel memory.  As long as pixel structure data is read correctly from the file, this data can be stored directly to pixels[i][j].

Comment: @Schwern -  I modified the code such that the pixel double pointer can now be  can be assigned with pixel data structure that is read from the file.